# What are use cases of LU decomposition and QR factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra

What are use cases of LU decomposition and QR factorization? In overlapping use cases (e.g., solving linear systems), what are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 0):

The $LU$ decomposition factorizes a matrix into a lower triangular matrix $L$ and an upper triangular matrix $U$. The systems $L(Ux)=b$ and $Ux=L^{-1}b$ require fewer additions and multiplications to solve, compared with the original system $Ax=b$, though one might **require significantly more digits** in inexact arithmetic such as floating-point.

Similarly, the $QR$ decomposition expresses $A$ as $QR$ with $Q$ an orthogonal matrix and $R$ an upper triangular matrix. The system $Q(Rx) = b$ is solved by $Rx = Q^Tb = c$, and the system $Rx = c$ is solved by 'back substitution'. The number of additions and multiplications required is about twice that of using the $LU$ solver (as you go through gram schmidt process of orthogonalization to make $Q$), but no more digits are required in inexact arithmetic because the $QR$ decomposition is **numerically stable**.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the systems $L(Ux) = b$ and $Ux = L^{-1} b$ require fewer additions and multiplications to solve compared with the original system $Ax = b$? This is one way of solving $Ax = b$! And it's a standard way at that. If you ask software to solve $Ax = b$, most likely it will compute an $LU$ factorization of $A$ and then solve precisely these systems $L(Ux) = b$ and $Ux = L^{-1}b$.

Comment: How is QR decomposition numerically stable?